# Align ListView items in a chat

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

Right now this chat bot aligns all of its display text to the left. The user input should align to the right, but not sure how to do that. I tried adding a `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` to the `ListView`, but it moves the entire list of bot/user chats to the right. I only want the user input text to be right-aligned. But how? I also looked up different `ItemTemplate` choices for `ListView` but none have what I need. I would accept a solution in XAML or programmatically in C#.

[image]

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="StudyBot.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:StudyBot"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MessagesListDataTemplate">
            <Grid x:Name="Text" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5">
                <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="deepskyblue" CornerRadius="7">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.9*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Background="#2f5cb6"/>
        <Border Grid.Column ="1" Background="#1f3d7a"/>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#152951"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" >
            <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="380" Width="900" Margin="20,25,15,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="300*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ListView x:Name="MessagesList" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessagesListDataTemplate}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="NewMessageTextBox" Grid.Row="2" KeyUp="NewMessageTextBox_KeyUp" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Button x:Name="button" Content="SEND" Foreground="#2f5cb6" Margin="15,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Send" Grid.Row="3" />

                <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" Margin="779,0,20,0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Mic">
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Microphone" Foreground="#2f5cb6"/>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,20,20,20">
            <Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" Width="1150">
                <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="White" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

                <Pivot.RightHeader>
                    <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Compact">
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Previous" Click="BackButton_Click"/>
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Next" Click="NextButton_Click"/>
                    </CommandBar>
                </Pivot.RightHeader>
                <PivotItem Header="Encyclopedia">
                    <WebView x:Name="Encyclopedia" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1150" MinHeight="500" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" >
                    </WebView>
                </PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="Microsoft Academic">
                    <WebView x:Name="MicrosoftAcademic" Width="1150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LoadCompleted="Journals_LoadCompleted" MinHeight="500" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" />
                </PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="News / Blogs">
                    <WebView x:Name="NewsBlogs" Width="1150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="500" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" />
                </PivotItem>
            </Pivot>
        </StackPanel>
        <Image Width="160" Source="Assets/robot-face.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,60,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="160" />
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="38" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,70,10,10" Text="Study Bot"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Updated MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="StudyBot.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:StudyBot"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MessagesListDataTemplate">
            <Grid x:Name="Text" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5">
                <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="deepskyblue" CornerRadius="7">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="{Binding IsUserText, Converter={StaticResource InverserBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5" />
                </Border>
                <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="deepskyblue" CornerRadius="7">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding IsUserText, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.9*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Background="#2f5cb6"/>
        <Border Grid.Column ="1" Background="#1f3d7a"/>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#152951"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" >
            <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="380" Width="900" Margin="20,25,15,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="300*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ListView x:Name="MessagesList" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessagesListDataTemplate}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="NewMessageTextBox" Grid.Row="2" KeyUp="NewMessageTextBox_KeyUp" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Button x:Name="button" Content="SEND" Foreground="#2f5cb6" Margin="15,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Send" Grid.Row="3" />

                <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" Margin="779,0,20,0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Mic">
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Microphone" Foreground="#2f5cb6"/>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,20,20,20">
            <Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" Width="1150">
                <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="White" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

                <Pivot.RightHeader>
                    <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Compact">
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Previous" Click="BackButton_Click"/>
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Next" Click="NextButton_Click"/>
                    </CommandBar>
                </Pivot.RightHeader>
                <PivotItem Header="Encyclopedia">
                    <WebView x:Name="Encyclopedia" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1150" MinHeight="500" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" >
                    </WebView>
                </PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="Microsoft Academic">
                    <WebView x:Name="MicrosoftAcademic" Width="1150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LoadCompleted="Journals_LoadCompleted" MinHeight="500" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" />
                </PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="News / Blogs">
                    <WebView x:Name="NewsBlogs" Width="1150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="500" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" />
                </PivotItem>
            </Pivot>
        </StackPanel>
        <Image Width="160" Source="Assets/robot-face.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,60,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="160" />
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="38" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,70,10,10" Text="Study Bot"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a combination of C#, XAML that works. I added this to my `MainPage()`:

```
// Add an event handler for the ContainerContentChanging event of the ListView
MessagesList.ContainerContentChanging += OnContainerContentChanging;
```

Added this function in the same file:

```
private void OnContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.InRecycleQueue) return;

    // Currently we are adding messages to the ListView.ItemSource as Activity objects
    // since this handler is called when the content changes (an item is added)
    // intercept the item as an activity and set its horizontal alignment accordingly
    Activity message = args.Item as Activity;
    args.ItemContainer.HorizontalAlignment = (message.From.Name == botHandle) ? HorizontalAlignment.Right : HorizontalAlignment.Left;
}
```

The above code corresponds to my `ListView`(and its template) in XAML of the above file:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MessagesListDataTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="TextB" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5">
            <Border>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="500" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="MessagesList" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessagesListDataTemplate}" Margin="5, 5, 5, 15"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one additional property in your Model something like `IsUserText` and then create two `TextBlock` one with left alignment and another with right alignment, you can set the `Visibility` of the TextBlock based on the `IsUserText` property.

Your `DataTemplate` should look something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MessagesListDataTemplate">
   <Grid x:Name="Text" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5">
     <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="deepskyblue" CornerRadius="7">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility={Binding IsUserText, Converter={StaticResource InverserBoolToVisibilityConverter}} Margin="5, 5, 5, 5" />
     </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="deepskyblue" CornerRadius="7">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility={Binding IsUserText, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}} Margin="5, 5, 5, 5" />
     </Border>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

EDIT:

Also if you don't want to use two `TextBlock's`, you can write converter for `HorizontalAlignment` and can set `Left` or `Right` based on the `'IsUserText` property

Comment: That looks great, although you did not include the quotes around the outer {}, but I added that and it resolved. But now when I enter text into the chat, I get a new error: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'`

Comment: When I comment out that line, I get a different error: `global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` on line 53 of my App.g.i.cs file. If you want me to post that file, I can.

Comment: Did you wrote Converter's which I mentioned in the Xaml?

Comment: Yeah, I copied it exactly, except adding the missing quotes. So now it looks like this: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding IsUserText, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5" />`

Comment: I added the whole thing you added (FYI), but that converter line looks like the one in my previous comment, if that's what you were asking about.

Comment: Can you share your Xaml file, seems like you are missing something.

Comment: Sure thing, I added an updated version of my xaml. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you haven't added converter's.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean. Can you provide it in your answer? Then I can try test it.